# Worker nodes not attaching to AWS EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-eks

I'm creating a 2 node AWS EKS cluster using aws cli in a .sh script.  The script below creates the control plane and 2 ECS instances for worker nodes, but the nodes don't get attached to the cluster.  When I check for nodes I get

```
$ kubectl get nodes
No resources found
```

Do I need a network interface?  What about using a nodegroup instead?

Here's the script:

```
current_time=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S.%3N")
file_name="eks.cluster.ids_${current_time}.txt"

VPC_ID=$(aws ec2 create-vpc --cidr-block 10.0.0.0/16 --query 'Vpc.VpcId' --output text)
SUBNET_ID1=$(aws ec2 create-subnet --vpc-id $VPC_ID --cidr-block 10.0.1.0/24 --availability-zone us-west-1a --query 'Subnet.SubnetId' --output text)
SUBNET_ID2=$(aws ec2 create-subnet --vpc-id $VPC_ID --cidr-block 10.0.2.0/24 --availability-zone us-west-1b --query 'Subnet.SubnetId' --output text)
SG_ID=$(aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name my-sg --description "EKS Security Group" --vpc-id $VPC_ID --query 'GroupId' --output text)
aws iam create-role --role-name dean-eks-role --assume-role-policy-document file://eks-role-trust-policy.json
aws iam attach-role-policy --role-name dean-eks-role --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
ROLE_ARN=$(aws iam get-role --role-name dean-eks-role --query 'Role.Arn' --output text)
aws eks create-cluster --name dean-eks-cluster --role-arn $ROLE_ARN --resources-vpc-config subnetIds=$SUBNET_ID1,$SUBNET_ID2,securityGroupIds=$SG_ID
sleep 5

aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name dean-eks-key --query 'KeyMaterial' --output text > dean-eks-key.pem

NODE_ID1=$(aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-01cff12e087f492c6 --count 1 --instance-type t2.medium --subnet-id $SUBNET_ID1 --security-group-ids $SG_ID --key-name dean-eks-key --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId' --output text)
NODE_ID2=$(aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-01cff12e087f492c6 --count 1 --instance-type t2.medium --subnet-id $SUBNET_ID1 --security-group-ids $SG_ID --key-name dean-eks-key --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId' --output text)

aws eks describe-cluster --name dean-eks-cluster --query cluster.status
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name dean-eks-cluster
sleep 5
```

Comment: What's the full output of your script when using `bash -x script.sh` replacing `script.sh` with the name of your Bash script? Also note, this way of provisioning infrastructure is not really ideal. For EKS specifically, https://eksctl.io/ is amazing just so that you're aware :)

Comment: How do your instances know which cluster to join?

Comment: eksctl is great, but I need this to work with Localstack as well and it doesn't support eksctl.  The `kubectl label nodes ...` command (not in my script) is supposed to let the nodes know which cluster to join, but it doesn't work.  AWS CLI apparently can't create an EKS cluster with worker nodes.